# Gtk.Scale value-changed signal vs drag-end?

Tags: gtk

Question in brief: **Does the `Gtk.Scale` widget have a `drag-end` signal as opposed to `value-changed`?**

I'm using a gtk scale widget (a slider) and according to [the docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkRange.html#GtkRange-value-changed) I should use the `value-changed` signal to detect when the user changes the slider.

Now the user grabs the slider and drags it to their desired value. When they have **finished** choosing their desired value (i.e. finished dragging), I want to do some stuff.

However, the `value-changed` signal gets emitted *each time* the value changes *including* while the user is still in the process of dragging the slider to their desired value, so I get one of these signals for *every value* in between the start value and the end value.

This introduces significant lag into my program and all uncessarily.

So - is there a way I can listen for a signal that fires when the user has *finished* changing the value on the slider, as opposed to a signal that fires every time the value changes?

At the moment I am throttling the calls by waiting some small set amount of time before executing my code, responding only to the last `value-changed` signal I receive in that period. This works OK, but I was just wondering if there is a more appropriate signal I should be listening to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `gtk_range_set_update_policy()` function.
You want to set policy to `GTK_UPDATE_DISCONTINUOUS`.

Comment: Wow, this is *exactly* what I wanted! Unfortunately [the docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkRange.html#gtk-range-set-update-policy) says it's deprecated since 2.24 with no replacement (what?!?!) "if you require delayed updates, do it yourself". awwww.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`change-value`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/2.24/GtkRange.html#GtkRange-change-value) signal instead. The second argument is `Gtk.ScrollType`. Comparing this with `Gtk.ScrollType.JUMP` should produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

In GTK+3 (at least), `Scale` inherits from `Widget`, which emits the `button-release-event` signal.

Answer (score 0):

There's no public API to do that. I think your approach is fine.

Comment: aww, OK. Well it's not a big deal, because the throttling works. cheers.