# python global value return to default after being set by thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a python script, that change the value of global variable VOL when the scale bar changes value. the value of VOL is read by the thread with function 'check_keys' every free moments. However, after the scale changes value, say "40", VOL only stay at 40 for once, then return to zero, strangely... I was expecting it was set to 40 until the next scale change.

Where did I make the mistake?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from Xlib.display import Display
from multiprocessing import Process
import threading
import os
import time
import gtk

VOL=0

class StatusIcon:
    def __init__(self):
        self.statusicon = gtk.StatusIcon()
        self.statusicon.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_HOME)
        self.statusicon.connect("popup-menu", self.right_click_event)
        self.statusicon.connect("activate", self.win_toggle)
        self.statusicon.set_tooltip("StatusIcon Example")

        self.window = gtk.Window()
        self.window.set_default_size(200, -1)

        adjustment = gtk.Adjustment(0, 0, 100, 5, 10, 0)
        self.scale = gtk.HScale(adjustment)
        self.scale.set_digits(0)
        self.scale.set_update_policy(gtk.UPDATE_DELAYED)

        self.visible=1
        self.window.connect("destroy", lambda w: w.hide_all())
        self.scale.connect("value-changed", self.scale_moved)

        self.window.add(self.scale)

        self.win_build()
        self.window.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS)
        p = Process(target=self.check_keys)
        p.start()


    def right_click_event(self, icon, button, time):
        menu = gtk.Menu()

        about = gtk.MenuItem("About")
        quit = gtk.MenuItem("Quit")

        about.connect("activate", self.show_about_dialog)
        quit.connect("activate", gtk.main_quit)

        menu.append(about)
        menu.append(quit)
        menu.show_all()

        menu.popup(None, None, gtk.status_icon_position_menu, button, time, self.statusicon)

    def show_about_dialog(self, widget):
        about_dialog = gtk.AboutDialog()

        about_dialog.set_destroy_with_parent(True)
        about_dialog.set_name("StatusIcon Example")
        about_dialog.set_version("1.0")
        about_dialog.set_authors(["Andrew Steele"])

        about_dialog.run()
        about_dialog.destroy()

    def scale_moved(self, widget):
        global VOL
        VOL = self.scale.get_value()
        print VOL

    def win_build(self):
        self.window.show_all()

    def win_toggle(self, widget):
        self.win_build()


    #def scale_moved(self, widget):
        #print self.scale.get_value()

    def check_keys(self):
        #global VOL
        disp = Display()
        okeymap = ZERO
        hold = 0
        samp_inv=0.02
        while 1:
            #print VOL
            keymap = disp.query_keymap() 
            if keymap not in ignorelist: 
                if keymap==okeymap:
                    hold=hold+1
                    if hold>0:
                        time.sleep(samp_inv)
                        continue
                else:
                    hold=0

                if keymap==BACK:
                    print "BACK"
                    print VOL
                    p = Process(target=play_key, args=("play -v "+str(VOL)+" /home/seanchu/Software/keypress/sounds/Back.wav",))
                elif keymap==SPACE:
                    print "SPACE"
                    print VOL
                    p = Process(target=play_key, args=("play -v "+str(VOL)+" /home/seanchu/Software/keypress/sounds/Space.wav",))
                elif keymap==ENTER:
                    print "ENTER"
                    print VOL
                    p = Process(target=play_key, args=("play -v "+str(VOL)+" /home/seanchu/Software/keypress/sounds/typewriterding.wav",))
                else:
                    print "KEY"
                    print VOL
                    p = Process(target=play_key, args=("play -v "+str(VOL)+" /home/seanchu/Software/keypress/sounds/keyn.wav",))
                p.start()
                time.sleep(0.2)
            else:
                time.sleep(samp_inv)

StatusIcon()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: This probably answered your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193365/gtk-scale-value-changed-signal-vs-drag-end. The expected value, 40, is basically erased by subsequent call to ``value-changed`` event

Comment: thx Anthony, but that's not it. Seems like if I set VOL=5 in the beginning, VOL will always return to 5. I dont understand why. why is VOL=5 executed more than once?